# Echo Numeric Value properly

Tags: php, arrays, echo, currency, numeric

I am trying to echo an array as a price in php, if the price is for example £2.55 is comes up as £2.55, if it is £2.50 is comes up as £2.5 , how can I get it to add the zero on the end ?.

My Mysql DB field is currently set to decimal(10,2)
Many Thanks 
:-)
Merry Christmas !

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#

```
<?php 
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_dashboard WHERE cf_id =    '1'") or die(mysql_error());
$oilprice = mysql_fetch_object($query);
 $oilpricegasoil = $oilprice->oilpricegasoil;
 $oilpricederv = $oilprice->oilpricederv;
$oilpricekero = $oilprice->oilpricekero;
?>



<tr><?php $gasoilprice = $oilpricegasoil + $row->gasoilmargin;
              $dervprice = $oilpricederv + $row->dervmargin;
              $keroprice = $oilpricekero + $row->keromargin;?>

        <td><?php echo $row->leadname; ?></td>
        <td><?php  echo $row->businessname; ?></td>
        <td><?php  echo $row->postcode; ?></td>
        <td><?php  echo $row->gasoiluser; ?></td>
        <td><?php  echo $row->dervuser; ?></td>
        <td><?php  echo $row->kerouser; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo '£'; echo $gasoilprice; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo '£'; echo $dervprice; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo '£'; echo $keroprice; ?></td>
```

Comment: Merry Christmas to you too :)  Can you give us a small code snippet that repros this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Simple formatting

Try [the `number_format` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
<?php
  $test = 2.50;
  echo "£", number_format($test, 2); // 2 decimal places
?>
```

> £2.50

- http://codepad.org/opf0j6kV

Be careful because this will round `.005` to the next highest cent, which isn't always what you want:

- http://codepad.org/IQvYDXnE

If you need different rounding, try using:

- [`round()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.round.php)
- [`ceil()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php)
- [`floor()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php)

#### Money formatting

You could also try [the `money_format` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php), though you'll need to make sure your locale is set correctly for it to work.

```
money_format('%.2n', $number); // 2 decimal points, with national currency symbol
```

#### Use a function

Either way, I recommend you push the conversion into a function, so you can reuse it throughout your code and don't have to repeat your number formatting:

```
function toCurrency($number)
{
  return '£' . number_format($number, 2);
}

// ...

<td><?php echo toCurrency($gasoilprice); ?></td>
<td><?php echo toCurrency($dervprice); ?></td>
<td><?php echo toCurrency($keroprice); ?></td>
```

Comment: Thankyou, that works perfectly :-) , I will accept your answer in 5 mins, when the system lets me, seasons greetings :o)